# Not updating database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have the following two classes generated by Entity Framework..

```
public partial class Datagrid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public partial class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext()
        : base("name=SampleDbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Datagrid> Datagrids { get; set; }
}
```

i have a WPF application where I have a list view containing checkboxs for each column.. I have written the to logic to find what are the checkboxes that are checked in the list view.. But when I iterate through the checked boxes and try to save to the database, database is not updating please help..
dg is object of type Datagrid..
db is object of type SampleDbContext

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in myBoxes)
{
    dg.IsChecked = cb.IsChecked; //I want to update each column with the checked value in the listview. cb.Ischecked works perfectly..It says true for the checkboxes that are checked else false
    db.SaveChanges(); //NOT updating the database
}
```

Comment: How is `dg` getting set each time?

Comment: Forevery checkbox in my application, I want to assign the checkbox value to the Ischecked that is bit value in the database

Answer (score 1):

Your variable 'dg' will need to be part of the databaseContext's ('db' in your code) DataGrid's Property. An example:

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in myBoxes)
{      
    dg.IsChecked = cb.IsChecked; 
    db.DataGrids.Add(dg);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

.SaveChanges() will only flush items assigned to the DataGrid property to the database.

Comment: Thanks anyway..But I am getting an exception like Unhandled System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll....Please help. Is it because of the mismatch of nullable type in the database..

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I'm not entirely clear on if the checkboxes need to be created each time or just updated.  If created, it will be somewhat like the other answer.  However, you were likely getting the `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException` due to attempting to add a new Datagrid without providing a `Name` and `Location`, which are not nullable and are not (presumably) automatically populated like `Id`:

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in myBoxes)
{      
    Datagrid dg = new Datagrid
      {
        Name = "NameGoesHere"; // Maybe you're wanting to use cb.Name or cb.Text?
        Location = "Location Here";
        IsChecked = cb.IsChecked;
      };


    db.DataGrids.Add(dg);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

If you're just updating instead, I'm still not sure where you're setting `dg`, but perhaps you might want to look it up from :

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in myBoxes)
{
  Datagrid dg = db.DataGrids.Where(g => g.Name == cb.Name).SingleOrDefault();
  // etc.
```

**Edit based on comments:**

If you're doing two-way binding and have directly bound `CheckBox`es to the `IsChecked` values of `Datagrid` entities, you shouldn't need to do anything other than simply call `db.SaveChanges();` when you're ready to save.  The bound `Datagrid` entities will be updated on their own.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Basically I have a listview control with checkbox for every row. The value of the check box whether they are checked or not is coming from DataGrid class IsChecked property as mentioned above. So on the UI I have a button along with listview. So basically if the user changes any checkboxes to checked or unchecked, I want to save what he checks into the database(Two way Binding). I have code to determine what checkboxes the user has checked or unchecked..I want to save these changes.Basically update IsChecked value of the Database using Entity Framework.

Comment: Your solution is so clear thanks.. But I dont want to edit the name and location columns which are not null as you said. I only want to update the IsChecked column i.e update single column for every row. Is there a way of doing it..

Comment: Added to answer above--if you're truly doing two-way binding, just be sure it's set up right and then all you'll need to do is save.  No need to track all the checkboxes yourself again.